# Jasmine: Adding Lodash to Testing

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm using lodash in my application/component. Jasmine is complaining:

Failed: Cannot read property 'eq' of undefined

I've added, lodash to my karma.conf

such as:{ pattern: './node_modules/lodash/lodash.min.js', included: true, watched: false }

Still getting the issue, what is the correct way of including lodash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding these lines to "main.ts":

#### main.ts

```typescript
//...

import _ from 'lodash';

declare global {
  const _: _.LoDashStatic;
}

//...
```

Also, I added lodash to karma.conf.js:

#### karma.conf.js

```typescript
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
          basePath: '',
          frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
          files: [
            'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js'
          ],
          //...
```

Answer (score 7):

Just import lodash like this in your component:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash'
```

Comment: I've done that, unfortunately no problem in components. but Issue in spec.ts

Comment: Thanks this solve my problem !!, not sure why but works.  @TaranjitKang checkout the following repo so you can test the solution. https://github.com/hummorsa/angular-cli-lodash-test/

Comment: thanks! can anybody explain why this is working :D