# Add External dependency for karma testing using Angular 4 CLI - Lodash case

Tags: angular, angular-cli, lodash, karma-webpack

I setup a simple Angular CLI repo to demonstrate my problemm here, https://github.com/hummorsa/angular-cli-lodash-test/

Basically in this test:

```
it('should sort Users', async(() => {
 const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.componentInstance.transform();
  expect(fixture.componentInstance.users[0].age).toEqual(34);
```

}));

I get the error when running the tests,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortBy' of undefined

This is the code:

```
public transform (): any {
this.users =  _.sortBy(this.users, 'age');
```

}

So basically karma is not getting the reference of lodash while doing the test. I tried some fixes from other answers but I am unable to make it work.

It looks that I need to include the reference in some place, not sure where/how to do it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

After keep doing research ant testing, I fond the solution, and is in the last commit of this repo: https://github.com/hummorsa/angular-cli-lodash-test/, is possible to clone the repo and run 'ng test' to try it.

Basically the import in the typescript file of lodash need to be as follow:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash'
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45855755/3847132

Reason why it fit it: Still unknown.